# Trying to get XPath of a dropdown item on webpage in NewRelic monitor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, javascript

This is the code which I'm validating but its not able to get the Logout option under the dropdown. I copied the XPath value of Logout from the dropdown.

[image: code]

[image: code2]

This is what the dropdown looks like.

[image: drop]

This is the error while validating the same.

> TaskTimedOut: Task timed-out waiting for element to be visible using: By(xpath, //*[@id='settingsDd']/li[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDvtE.png)/a/span)

Actually what I figured out is the correct drop is not getting selected, instead of that there is a tour button which gets clicked & highlighted.
I have taken the XPath of the dropdown itself, but the wrong click happens.
If any syntax error, let me know.
Please assist.

Comment: Is that dropdown expanded on click or on hover?

Comment: @AlexeyR. it expands on hover

Comment: @Salman then please share your code how you hover the gear icon

Comment: @AlexeyR.Edited with SS of code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to click element to get your list expanded but you should actually hover it.

Instead of `.then(function (el) { el.click(); $browser.sleep(4000); })` (line 120)

try this:

`.then(function (el) { $browser.actions().mouseMove(el).perform(); $browser.sleep(4000); })`

[source of idea](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/how-to-handle-mouse-hover-for-a-drop-down-menu-in-newrelic-synthetics/56499)

Answer (score 0):

well based on your error, element is not visible, try an implicily wait to make sure element is visible before trying to click/hover it (you have to figure out if it´s an actual click or hover as well)

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then make sure your xpath is working correctly by getting only 1 result, use the "chropath" extension for chrome, is free.